# Should I check if the item exists on the page (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, select, input, null, isset

I want to apply value from input to select when document is ready. Everything works fine.

Do you recommend to check if both `select#city` and `input#city_hidden` exist to make this code better?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("select#city").val($("input#city_hidden").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision depends on numerous factors, not just this line of code.

Technically, you don't need to check if select#city exists. If it doesn't, jQuery will just do nothing as the $("select#city") selector will be empty.

Comment: Thanks. But what if $("select#city") exists, but $("input#city_hidden") - not? It works logically fine, but what about a perfect code?

Comment: Then the select value will be null. I can't tell whether this is acceptable or not just from your question. If you need a complete check, then just checking if input#city_hidden exists is not enough, you also need to check if $("input#city_hidden").val() is an acceptable select option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that $("input#city_hidden") and $("select#city") are always there - there is no reason to check. If they are a part of your html I would say a check is not necessary.

Comment: Well, it depends on the page loaded. I want to put that verification into a common js file so it is for any page, although only several pages have that items.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to check if items exist in a page you can use .length in an if statement.

```
if($('#myDiv').length){
    //#myDiv exists because the length is not 0
}
```

here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ajvp7/

Comment: The question is about do I need to check if both exist in my situation, or it is OK to skip that verification, and the code is just skipped if at least one of two items do not exist.